# Should I use C++ AMP if I'm already manually threading my application?

Tags: c++-amp

I'm not sure what C++ AMP is good for.  If I've already multithreaded my application (in this case, a ray tracer) to use all n cores on a system, *should I use C++ AMP*, or will this actually create more bottle necks? (when it tries to multithread, all CPU cores are already 100% utilized,)

Comment: Why "fix" something that doesn't need fixin'? IOW, why do you want to use AMP if you don't need it/have already implemented your thing without it?

Comment: I wanted to try for more speed, of course.

Comment: Well, just try it out. I don't think anyone can tell you beforehand if you'll manage to get more speed out of it - we don't have the slightest clue about how your code is written, and barely about what it actually does.

Comment: It's just basic parallelized ray tracing code.  Because there are n cores, you can trace n rays in parallel on the same geometry. "Trying it out" is actually really involved, so I'd like to know _something_ about AMP before I dive in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ AMP allows you to execute your code on the GPUs. Whether or not you would get performance depends on how well your computation would take advantage of the hardware. You would have much more cores on your disposal, but you need to transfer your data over PCIe, so your computation needs to be substantial to pay off the initial cost of data movement. Data parallel problems such as ray tracers are good match.

Check out introductory post on C++ AMP to learn more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/08/30/learn-c-amp.aspx

or watch introductory presentation on C++ AMP:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-802T

Comment: Just as a side-note: Windows 8 actually has the WARP (Windows Advanced Rasterization Platform) accelerator, which is CPU based and a possible C++ AMP target. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.danielmoth.com%2FBlog%2FRunning-C-AMP-Kernels-On-The-CPU.aspx&ei=e7l5ULqaK-nD0QHcqoGoCA&usg=AFQjCNG9yN87KFxTwD5PAaTqrQmi-ouV7w

Answer (score 1):

AMP is good when you want to calculate a huge array of data where each element or thread is independent to each other. For example, if you want to calculate the position of a particle in an array of 100M particles, it will take hours on the CPUs. However, on the GPU, each particle can be one thread, and a GPU can execute thousand of threads at a time. Compared to 8 cores CPU, you can only execute 8 threads at a time.